# iOS: BGProcessingTaskRequest gets killed due to high cpu usage

Tags: ios, background-process

I have an app that is requesting a `BGProcessingTaskRequest` -- this is the type of background activity that is encouraged to use if you have a process that is long running and advertised to even be able to retrain a machine learning model.

My background processing generally uses a `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))` but I can't completely control this as I also for instance use a private Core Data background context.

However, my process gets killed due to cpu usage.

```
Event:            cpu usage
Action taken:     Process killed
CPU:              48 seconds cpu time over 55 seconds (87% cpu average), exceeding limit of 80% cpu over 60 seconds
CPU limit:        48s
Limit duration:   60s
CPU used:         48s
CPU duration:     55s
Duration:         55.24s
Duration Sampled: 40.95s
Steps:            22
```

Why is iOS imposing a CPU limit when the process is advertised as "A request to launch your app in the background to execute a processing task that can take minutes to complete.". The device was also plugged in during the crash.

The high cpu usage obviously is on purpose and also happens in a low-level Accelerate framework operation that I could not even throttle if I wanted to.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is a problem I am also facing currently. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't think we're doing anything wrong. Even Apple processes (photoanalysisd,  CacheDeleteDaily, apfs_defragd...) are being killed in the same way. The feature just doesn't work as advertised

Comment: Also, even when I do throttle CPU usage, my background process still only gets to run for 5 minutes at a time before being forcibly expired

Comment: Unfortunately not. I wrote on the dev forums about it and also filed a bug (with not reponse yet: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690666)

Comment: In my case the background processing consists of many transactions so I'm able to do something useful by: (a) throttling CPU usage; (b) committing each transaction as the task progresses; (c) if task has not completed, reschedule it in the expiry handler. The task will run for 5 minutes at a time, but will run again some time later even when the device remains idle and connected to power